# Crystal Reports, IList<T> as DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

For a long time now since VS2002/2003 I been simple class that only required .rpt file and DataSet as DataSource to produce Crystal Report (such as .pdf, .doc, .xls .. etc). Since then, I never revisit the class (which delivery what I expected) even with the released of VS2005 & VS2008 and now VS2010.

But yesterday, I am just wondering, if passing Generics/`IList<T>` as datasource is now possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends if Crystal allows you to pass in a generics. However generics is really not really but more a compile-time blackmagic. So for Crystal to work it will need a thing.

The dataset carries over both structure for the Crystal designer to fields etc and data for the actual report. Basically the Dataset gives the same structure info returned from a DB.

IList would be able to give Crystal the structure info needed to create the Field List etc.